# Generic with question mark

Tags: java, generics, collections

How to construct instance of `Collection<Map<String, ?>>` ?

```
// works:
Collection<?> collection = new ArrayList<Object>();
ArrayList<?> arrayList = new ArrayList<Object>();

Map<String, ?> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
HashMap<String, ?> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

Collection<Map<String, Object>> collectionOfMaps = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> arrayListOfHashMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

// error:
ArrayList<HashMap<String, ?>> arrayListOfHashMapsWithQuestionMark = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
```

last one row does not compile with following error:

`incompatible types:  java.util.ArrayList<java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>> cannot be converted to java.util.ArrayList<java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String,?>>`

Why in arrayListOfHashMapsWithQuestionMark `Object` is invalid for question mark type?

Comment: What's the point in not using the diamond operator?

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Answer (score 1):

You need `ArrayList<? extends HashMap<String, ?>>`.

As all of the other examples demonstrate, e.g. `HashMap<String, Object>` is a *subtype* of `HashMap<String, ?>`.

Comment: I want to call method with `ArrayList<HashMap<String, ?>>` parameter so i can not change signature and  need to construct instance of this type.

Comment: why not just do `new ArrayList<HashMap<String, ?>>()`?

Comment: @TrevorKropp it works but with copying whole list to new ArrayList instance

Comment: A workaround would be to cast the `ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>` to the type you need from the answer. Then you can do an unchecked cast to the type indicated by the method signature.

Comment: @Silence why does using `new ArrayList<HashMap<String, ?>>()` instead of `new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>()` require “copying whole list”? That sentence makes no sense.